# I'm trying to get my function to perform the given parameter

Tags: python-3.x

I've identified input for 2 numbers and then asked for input user option. When I try to run the function using the input it ignores all of my if, elif and goes straight to the else every time.

I've tried several different ways to perform (+, -, *, /) based on input from user.

```
num1 = input('Select your first number')
num2 = input('Select your second number')
select_option = input('Select the option you want to perform')
option1 = int(num1)+int(num2)
option2 = int(num1)-int(num2)
option3 = int(num1)*int(num2)
option4 = int(num1)/int(num2)
def performCalculation(select_option):
    if select_option == 1:
        print(option1)
    elif select_option== 2:
        print(option2)
    elif select_option== 3:
        print(option3)
    elif select_option== 4:
        print(option4)
    else:
        print('Have a great day!')
print(performCalculation(select_option))
```

I'm trying to input 3 so my numbers will multiply, but eac htime it skips to print('Have a great day!')

Comment: `select_option` isn't a number, it's apparently a string representing an operator. What is your intent in `select_option == 1`? Did you mean to check it against `"+"` and the like?

Comment: If they selected 1 I wanted them to add the numbers or if they selected 2 it would subtract.

Comment: I figured it out I needed to put it as int(select_option) ==1

Comment: I wouldn't constantly call `int` like you are. Just convert the String once, save that, the use the number where you need it.

Comment: The `option` variables are not really needed when you could directly print the result of the expression. What might be cleaner actually is to assign a `result` variable in the `if`/`elif`/`else` blocks and then `print(result)` after.

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a String, and `1` does not equal `"1"`:

```
>>> 1 == "1"
False
```

You need to parse the returned String as an number:

```
select_option = int(input('Select the option you want to perform'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It skips to the last line because you are not converting select option to an integer. In the performCalculation(select_option) function you are comparing a string to an integer. So it will not be equal to each other. Just make sure to convert the select_option to an integer like you did with num1 and num2.

```
num1 = input('Select your first number: ')
num2 = input('Select your second number: ')
select_option = input('Select the option you want to perform: ')
select_option=int(select_option)
option1 = int(num1)+int(num2)
option2 = int(num1)-int(num2)
option3 = int(num1)*int(num2)
option4 = int(num1)/int(num2)
def performCalculation(select_option):
    if select_option == 1:
        print(option1)
    elif select_option== 2:
        print(option2)
    elif select_option== 3:
        print(option3)
    elif select_option== 4:
        print(option4)
    else:
        print('Have a great day!')
print(performCalculation(select_option))
```